# How to run a command line function in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, exec, external

I am having some issues running a program from a command line in php. Whenever I run the program in the command line, the proper file is created and it works perfectly. However when I go and put it in my php and use the exec() function, nothing happens.

In the end I want the user to be able to select the parameters he wants to run on the external program, but for now im just trying to run it with hard coded values in....

Here is the command that I use to run the program from the command line and its parameters.

```
 [path1] -p blastp -d [parameter1] -i [path2] -e [parameter2] -m 9 -o [path3]

 where [path1] is the path to ../blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall, 
       [path2] is the path to sample.fasta
       [path3] is the path for the output file (you may want to create another folder for generating the output)
       [parameter1] is the name of database chosen by the user from your page (eg. Human.db, Viruses.db, etc)
       [parameter2] is the E-value given by the user from your page(eg. 0.0001, 1, 1000, etc)
```

The actual code I would type into the command line would be

```
~/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i ~/temp/sample.fasta -m 9 -o output'
```

Here is my code so far.

```
<form method="POST", action="/~cs4380sp15grp4/home/blast.php">

<select id="database" name="database">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Database</option>
    <option value="Archaea">Archaea</option>
    <option value="Bacteria">Bacteria</option>
</select>

<select id="evalue" name="evalue">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> evalue <option>
    <option value="0.0001">0.0001</option>
    <option value="0.001">0.001</option>
</select>

<select id="hits" name="hits">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> Hits</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>

<input id="BlastSearch" type="text" name="BlastSearch" value='' />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button>
</form>
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../secure/database.php';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    if($mysqli->connect_error){
            exit('CON Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ' ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    //Insert the values into the database

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


            $db = $_POST['database'];
            $evalue = $_POST['evalue'];
            $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];

            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Job` (`uid`, `input`, `status`, `start_time`, `finish_time`) VALUES ('1', '" . $sequence . "', 'running' , NOW(), NULL)");

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `BLAST`(`database`, `evalue`, 'job_id') VALUES ('" . $db . "','" . $evalue . "', `1`)") or die(mysqli_error($db));

             exec(' /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/temp/sample.fasta -m 9 -o /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/temp/output');
    }



//    print "Connected! Host info: " . $mysqli->host_info . "<br>\n";
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

So my exec function isnt working in my php page because that same command works in the terminal.

Comment: Who do You run Your server as? Who do You run Your code from command line as? What are permissions and ownership of ~/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall?

Comment: I have the correct permissions

Comment: Once the command is running inside PHP, which in turn is inside the web server, it is not *you* that needs permissions, but *the web server*. Since this looks like a shared college system, there are likely other security configurations in place as well. Have you tried running a really simple command, just to prove that `exec` is working at all? (Number 1 tip for debugging: break the problem down to eliminate problems. The code posted here has lots of stuff outside the `exec` line which is - presumably - irrelevant to the problem. Strip it out!)

Answer (score 1):

`~` is the home folder of the currently active user. Php scripts are executed by the user `www-data`, the home folder is `/var/www`.

To fix this, use full paths. Example:

```
exec(' /home/username/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /home/username/temp/sample.fasta -m 9 -o output');
```

Comment: Add `>/var/www/log.txt` to redirect the command  output to a file. Open that file to get more information about the problem.

Comment: Just recplace your `exec` line: `exec('/home/username/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /home/username/temp/sample.fasta -m 9 -o output >/var/www/log.txt');` (and remove the space before the command)

Comment: okay thanks I will try it out. What does this do? I cant find this file

Comment: There should be a file in `/var/www/log.txt` that contains all the output that is generated by your command. If not, you can try to use `echo exec(xy) `

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path, i.e..:

```
   exec(' /full/path/to/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /full/path/to/temp/sample.fasta -m 9 -o output');
    }
```

Comment: In your case, you may want to use [realpath ($file)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)